# How to show and hide value using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the below code, I have select option with values Display and Hide:

- if i click Display it should show values
- if i click the hide it should hide the value.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Dropdown</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="">
        Show HTML:
      <select ng-model="myVar">
          <option value="1">Display</option>
          <option value="2">Hide</option>
      </select>
        <div  ng-class="col-xs-4" ng-show="myVar">
            <form class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputFirstName" class="control-label col-xs-2">FirstName</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputFirstName" placeholder="First Name">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputLastName" class="control-label col-xs-2">LastName</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputLastName" placeholder="Last Name">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label col-xs-2">Email</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-10">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputPassword" class="control-label col-xs-2">Password</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-10">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-10">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you provide a working fiddle?. Also please format your Question correctly

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <body ng-app="">
        Show HTML:
      <select ng-model="myVar">
          <option value="1">Display</option>
          <option value="2">Hide</option>
      </select>
        <div  ng-class="col-xs-4" ng-show="myVar==1">
            <form class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputFirstName" class="control-label col-xs-2">FirstName</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputFirstName" placeholder="First Name">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputLastName" class="control-label col-xs-2">LastName</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputLastName" placeholder="Last Name">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label col-xs-2">Email</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-10">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputPassword" class="control-label col-xs-2">Password</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-10">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-10">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        
        
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

try `ng-class="{'your_class_name':( your_condition ) , 'other_class_name' : ('other_condition')}"`

```
ng-class="{'hidden' : ( myVar == '2' )}
```

put this directive on the element you want to show/hide

Answer (score -1):

Try like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dropdown</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="">
    Show HTML:
  <select ng-model="myVar">
      <option value="1">Display</option>
      <option value="2">Hide</option>
  </select>
    <div  ng-class="col-xs-4" ng-show="myVar == '1'">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputFirstName" class="control-label col-xs-2">FirstName</label>
                <div class="col-xs-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputFirstName" placeholder="First Name">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputLastName" class="control-label col-xs-2">LastName</label>
                <div class="col-xs-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputLastName" placeholder="Last Name">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label col-xs-2">Email</label>
                <div class="col-xs-10">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputPassword" class="control-label col-xs-2">Password</label>
                <div class="col-xs-10">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-10">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```